# Calculating Fleiss' kappa using the irr package in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am looking at whether there is agreement between a subject's standardized weight (light-for-age or heavy-for-age) in early life and adulthood. I have re-coded light-for-age as '1' and heavy-for-age as '2' and am calculating Fleiss' kappa using the irr package in R. My data are as follows:

```
phase1=c(2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2)
phase3=c(2,1,1,NA,2,1,2,1,NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA)
ydata=data.frame(phase1, phase3)
```

'phase 1' is early life and 'phase 3' is adulthood.

And here is my procedure:

```
library(irr)
phases=kappam.fleiss(ydata, exact=TRUE, detail=FALSE)
phases$value
```

Next, I want to look at whether those that are light-for-age ('1') in early life tend to remain light-for-age in adulthood:

```
phases2=kappam.fleiss(ydata[ydata$phase1==1, ], exact=TRUE, detail=FALSE)
phases2$value
```

Based on the data in the second analysis, I'd have expected a very high agreement, but I get an extremely low kappa. So I'm wondering if I might be implementing this incorrectly.

Comment: you have very few data points, the margins are unbalanced, and the pairwise agreement is high, in data like this the kappa is known to correct severely. you could use another coefficient (brennan-prediger, gwet ac1, I get .4 and .6 respectively) or just summarize the agreement percent which to me makes more sense in cases like this. regardless, this seems more like a question about the statistics, so maybe you should try [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I have posted to cross validated - thanks